# create string literal type from dyanamic array in typescript

Tags: typescript, tuples

I have this code which works great for a static array using `as const`

```
type ScaleKeys<A extends readonly unknown[]> = `${keyof A & `${number}`}x`;

const spacing = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4] as const;

type SpaceKeys = ScaleKeys<typeof spacing>; // works great with a static array

const a: SpaceKeys = '0x';
```

But having to statically declare a large static array is not great.

Is it possible to do this with a dynamic array:

I've tried this:

```
type ScaleKeys<A extends readonly unknown[]> = `${keyof A & `${number}`}x`;

const b: ReadonlyArray<number> = Array.from({ length: 20 });

type C = ScaleKeys<typeof b> // not sure if this is even possible
```

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgQwDYQNIRAZwDwEEoQAewEAdgCaZQBOEC5A9qUiFAK6kDWpDA7qQG0AugD4oAXigADACQBvThgYAzKPgBk0+aTYBbAEYRqAXynHCUgNwAoa3CaZgUTGARwAlqQDmEqAIAMADRQ-gB0AKzBAIzREcEATAlxUADMwSnJACxCUAhU9qSONtagkLCucGgYVJLwyFVY2KUQKs4Vnl4illAA9D1QvAzUnFRetAhOvO7AABa5zsAT7nC51NQIILYFjrkAXOVuDTVQAOT+hCfF2076+wBKdIzMILhrG9g6BkZikq-rIKFlNQGLoABRyKAobyzfbxfxQYwASmKzSgAGFfHUUOhGn93p9DNQRGI+lAeE5MGxaFB3KpZu4qAyCAA3MhQMAMTCYdz6FBAA) with the above.

Comment: What are you expect from `ScaleKeys<typeof b>` ? `${number}px`?

Comment: @captain-yossarian a string union  

'1x' | '2x' | '3x' .... etc. up to '20x'

Comment: Once `b` is just a `ReadonlyArray<number>` the compiler has no idea how long it is.  You can just *tell* it that `C` is `ScaleKeys<TupleLen<20>>` for an appropriately defined `TupleLen` type, like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mx5gXW), but there's no way for the compiler to keep track of `20` in the code you've written.  If the code I presented works for your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise please describe the failing use case in the [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If you want dynamicly create tuple, you can use this utility type:

```js
type Tuple<N extends number, Cache extends number[] = []> = Cache['length'] extends N ? Cache : Tuple<N, [...Cache, Cache['length']]>

// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
type Result = Tuple<20>
```

If you want to map it, consider this function:

```js
type Tuple<N extends number, Cache extends number[] = []> = Cache['length'] extends N ? Cache : Tuple<N, [...Cache, Cache['length']]>

type MapTuple<T extends ReadonlyArray<number>> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: `${Prop & string}x`
}

// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
type Result = Tuple<20>

const tuple = <Length extends number>(length: Length) =>
    new Array(length)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, index): `${number}x` => `${index}x`) as unknown as MapTuple<Tuple<Length>>

// ["0x", "1x", "2x",... "41x"]
const result = tuple(42)
```

[Playgrund](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBUCukA20A8A5W0AepoA7AEwGdZDEBbAI2gCcAaWAYQEMBjACzjwJPKVaDANoBdWAF5Y4gHxTWnHiIDkaQgHNQXFRL5EysbAH5F3OAC4EyNFmYiAdE-bnmL5WqJadYsbJAQMLAAsmyQSKgY8Dj4BuQAStBsxAD2hCjgAIL09Gzg6EJ09LLy0gDewLBVMgAK9CmQsACWhLAA1tDgKQBmCGJWAAYAJGV1DbAAZLCkoPQtGgC%20uAPACyAA9OsyAAzMAIzMAEzMAMzMACzMAKzMAGzMAOzMABzMAJz7u7B7B9-H32dvpdvjdvvdvk9vq9vm8xGAoHBEqREChQAoIrZDtt-MAOGkZrBQDY4NJ0AAZLzaGL8QyFBiyAAU6m8Vgpmm0AEopP5qhRoAB3WDZXLgJmUrgcyq86oObpNFAoBnbSXSmVUMIMhkAfWYLWIeA5gxGdPoSwG3NgwzKerwZq5bHIiEIbUIKX5rQdITCGKixPJ4pKGy2IgARNtcCHmCG9hGo4dY04HLAQ%20cYyG4XjCAT6NBkaiFETIgzzocOUA)

If you are interested in tuple manipulations, you can check my  [blog](https://catchts.com/tuples)